# Absolute continuity counterexample of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus

This example is from Stochastic Modelling and Applied Probability by Sören Asmussen (2010) p.358.

The setup is the following:

Let $\{Z_{t}\}$ be stochastic process on a Skorokhod space $D$ and a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$. Two such processes may be represented by measures $P$, $\tilde{P}$ on $(D,\mathcal{F})$.

One may study the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dP/d\tilde{P}$.

The author says, that this is too restrictive and gives the following example:

Consider the random walk of partial sums $\{S_{n}\}$ of $Z_{t}$ with incremental distribution $F,\tilde{F}$ with means $\mu\not=\tilde{\mu}$ and let $A:=\{S_{n}/n\rightarrow \mu\}$,$\tilde{A}:=\{S_{n}/n\rightarrow \tilde{\mu}\}$. The author states now, that $P$ is concentrated on $A$ and $\tilde{P}$ is concentrated on $\tilde{A}$, which are disjoint, which is finally excluding the absolute continuity.

Can someone explain me this more in detail? It looks like he is using the law of large numbers to argue that the measures are concentrated on the defined sets. (How?) But we need the iid case of some equidistant sequence $Z_{1},Z_{2},Z_{3},\ldots$ here for $S_{n}/n\rightarrow \mu$, which he hasn't mentioned explicitly in his example. But by saying that $\{S_{n}\}$ under $F,\tilde{F}$, has mean $\mu\not=\tilde{\mu}$ we can expect the iid case. Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typical, at least in my experience, that "random walks" unless otherwise stated are sums of iid random variables.  You can form two random walks with iid copies of normal distributions with means $\mu, \tilde{\mu}$ and variances $\sigma^2$ respectively.  Then by the law of large numbers, the averages of their partial sums will converge to the their respective means.

Comment: But then we expect from $Z_{t}$ to be i.i.d. to have $S_{n}$ i.id. Isn't that too restrictive? But the rest seems now clear thanks to your answer. But maybe i got s.th. wrong. We expect $S_{n}=X_{1}+\ldots+X_{n}$. How would one define the $X_{i}$, for which we require iid. By the increments?

Comment: @ziT   The $Z_t$ are iid but the $S_n$ are not i.i.d.  e.g. If $m \leq n$ then $\text{cov}(S_m, S_n) = \sum_{i =1, j=1}^{i=m, j =n}\text{cov}(Z_i, Z_j) = \sum_{i = 1}^m \text{var}(Z_i) \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. But how do i get i.i.d Sequence to apply law of large numbers for $S_{n}$.?

Comment: @ziT - The $Z_i$ are iid and the $S_n$ are their averages.  That is what is required to apply the strong law: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n Z_i \to \mu$

Comment: Now i got it. Thanks to you all!

Comment: @ziT   Happy to help.

Comment: One question: why we need incremental Distribution then?

Comment: Well if $Z_t$ is the process defined over all time then $S_n = Z_n$ for all $n$.  In that case, let $X_{n+1} = Z_{n+1} - Z_n$ and each $X_n$ has iid distribution $F$.  Then when I used a $Z$ in the above discussion replace it by $X$.  Same result.

Comment: Ok now we are done. Thanks!